# Kubuntu 12.04 CD/DVD drive no longer recognized

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, dvd, cd

Dear potential helpers,

I have the following problem on a circa-2008 Asus Laptop with Kubuntu 12.04.3 (3.2.0-39-generic-pae):
After months of working fine, the CD/DVD drive is no longer recognized.
When I insert a DVD or CD, it is neither listed in the devices widget nor in the places tab of dolphin. I guess this is not a hardware problem, since the drive is recognized in BIOS and I can boot from a Live-CD.

For a while, there was a 50% chance of making it work by restarting the laptop with the DVD already in drive. But even this workaround does no longer work.

I have done quite some research about this, but the other problem reports and solutions I could find were not helpful for my problem.
It would be great if you could assist me.

The following console outputs were made with a DVD inserted.

sudo lshw output:

```
        description: Notebook
    product: X51RL ()
    vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
    version: 1.0
    serial: NF1S8448510135
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook cpus=1 uuid=A42481DD-1ACB-B0ED-2E00-001FC6879476
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X51RL
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 204
          date: 02/25/2008
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU          550  @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.6.1
          serial: 0001-0661-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: Socket 478
          size: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx x86-64 constant_tsc up arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 19
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 1GiB
          capacity: 1GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous
             product: PartNum0
             vendor: Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum0
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: PartNum1
             vendor: Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum1
             slot: DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 01
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: latency=64
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS480 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:7000(size=4096) memory:f8800000-f88fffff memory:8ff00000-afefffff
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200M]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 5
                bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=64 mingnt=8
                resources: irq:17 memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:7800(size=256) memory:f88f0000-f88fffff memory:f88c0000-f88dffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS480 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:0 memory:f8900000-f89fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 00:15:af:93:06:8f
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.2.0-39-generic-pae firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
                resources: irq:16 memory:f89f0000-f89fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS480 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:0 ioport:8000(size=8192) memory:f8a00000-fc9fffff ioport:aff00000(size=536870912)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS480 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:0
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS480 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:22 ioport:e800(size=8) ioport:e400(size=4) ioport:e000(size=8) ioport:dc00(size=4) ioport:d800(size=16) memory:febffc00-febfffff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: Hitachi HTS54251
                vendor: Hitachi
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: BB2O
                serial: 080406BB2200WBE03NWA
                size: 111GiB (120GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=552d552d
              *-volume:0
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 5baf7d64-fd37-4711-9759-753571d2f88b
                   size: 20GiB
                   capacity: 20GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2012-09-20 16:08:52 filesystem=ext4 label=kubuntu lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-09-20 16:45:32 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2013-09-27 12:29:31 state=mounted
              *-volume:1
                   description: Linux swap volume
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   version: 1
                   serial: b1a54e61-6106-4c1d-8516-7f77f23e1a23
                   size: 3906MiB
                   capacity: 3906MiB
                   capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
              *-volume:2
                   description: EXT3 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   logical name: /home
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: fd3ab5b0-380b-4edc-9d52-094ce4db6328
                   size: 87GiB
                   capacity: 87GiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files recover ext3 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2008-07-14 19:39:01 filesystem=ext3 modified=2013-09-27 12:29:33 mount.fstype=ext3 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2013-09-27 12:29:33 state=mounted
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI0)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:febfe000-febfefff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI1)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:febfd000-febfdfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI2)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:febfc000-febfcfff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI3)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:febfb000-febfbfff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB (OHCI4)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:febfa000-febfafff
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 13.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:19 memory:febff800-febff8ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 13
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:b00(size=16)
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: SB600 IDE
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=64
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ff00(size=16)
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:febf4000-febf7fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:a000(size=8192) memory:fca00000-feafffff memory:cff00000-dfefffff
           *-pcmcia
                description: CardBus bridge
                product: RL5c476 II
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: pci@0000:08:01.0
                version: b4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pcmcia bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=yenta_cardbus latency=176 maxlatency=5 mingnt=128
                resources: iomemory:b00c09080-b00c0907f irq:21 memory:38000000-38000fff ioport:a400(size=256) ioport:a000(size=256) memory:d0000000-d3ffffff memory:3c000000-3fffffff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.1
                bus info: pci@0000:08:01.1
                version: 18
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:23 memory:feaffc00-feaffcff
           *-generic:1
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.2
                bus info: pci@0000:08:01.2
                version: 09
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm cap_list
                configuration: driver=r592 latency=0
                resources: irq:23 memory:feaff800-feaff8ff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 7
                bus info: pci@0000:08:07.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 00:1f:c6:87:94:76
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.2.100 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:20 ioport:b800(size=256) memory:feaff400-feaff4ff
```

sudo wodim --devices output:

```
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (0 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sudo lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
parport_pc             32114  0 
bluetooth             158479  10 rfcomm,bnep
ppdev                  12849  0 
dm_crypt               22528  0 
snd_hda_codec_si3054    12864  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
snd_hda_intel          32719  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
pcmcia                 39826  0 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
psmouse                86520  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
r592                   17808  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
yenta_socket           27465  0 
snd                    62218  16 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
pcmcia_rsrc            18367  1 yenta_socket
memstick               15857  1 r592
pcmcia_core            21511  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
soundcore              14635  1 snd
sp5100_tco             13495  0 
i2c_piix4              13093  0 
usblp                  17885  0 
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
joydev                 17393  0 
ath5k                 145127  0 
ath                    19387  1 ath5k
mac80211              436493  1 ath5k
asus_laptop            23693  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 asus_laptop
mac_hid                13077  0 
input_polldev          13648  1 asus_laptop
shpchp                 32265  0 
cfg80211              178877  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
radeon                738031  2 
8139too                23283  0 
8139cp                 26759  0 
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
ttm                    65344  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 radeon
pata_atiixp            12999  0 
drm                   197641  4 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 radeon
video                  19115  0 
ati_agp                13242  0
```

sudo mount output:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext3 (rw)
```

Comment: I was able to find the cause of the problem. Seems like I was lucky the last time I tried to boot from a Live-CD... it was a hardware problem. There was a piece of paper stuck in the bottom portion of the CD-Rom Drive, preventing the drive from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What does `cat /dev/cdrom` output? [to see whether the kernel recognizes any device]. I'll update and improve this answer as responses arrive. Also please provide the system log by running `dmesg`, which outputs the system log or KSystemLog.

Comment: thanks for your help! i was able to find the cause of the problem. it was a hardware problem after all.